# Using CSV to update records in pre-exisiting SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server

My SQL Server 2012 table is `CUST_TABLE`. It already has a lot of customer records (more than 10,000).

I have a CSV with the first column customer number which is my primary key. The second column has email addresses. The first row of this CSV contains columns heading custnum and email. The CSV has 125 data rows. I am using SSMS and want to update just 125 customer records and change their email.

The only solution I found was to have update statements to change the data. Is there any other easier way to do this? Like using the import data function by right-clicking on the database and then hovering over tasks. Thank you.

Comment: Some ideas: https://www.google.co.uk/search?safe=active&ei=E5RXWsmaD4XJwAKDgrCQBg&q=t-sql+bulk+update+from+csv&oq=t-sql+bulk+update+from+csv&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i22i30k1.2159.4506.0.4699.19.14.3.0.0.0.126.1472.6j8.14.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..2.14.1266...33i22i29i30k1j33i160k1.0.0TpiJ3ykzzg

Comment: If you aren't doing this on an hourly basis then the "add a calculation to generate UPDATE statements" solution is probably the quickest/ easiest.

Comment: Create a cell in your document and add the SQL using expressions from the other fields.

Answer (score 0):

Read the csv into a temp table, then update your table using the temp table.

For example:

```
USE yourdb;

GO

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#tmp', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #tmp;

GO

CREATE TABLE #tmp (
    t_cust_nr   NVARCHAR(MAX),
    t_email     NVARCHAR(MAX)
)

SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Read the csv, skip the first row
BULK INSERT #tmp 
    FROM 'C:\path\to\your.csv' 
    WITH (FIRSTROW = 2, FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', ROWTERMINATOR ='\n');

-- Trim whitespace
UPDATE #tmp
    SET t_cust_nr = LTRIM(RTRIM(t_cust_nr)),
        t_email = LTRIM(RTRIM(t_email));


-- Add your update statement here... 
-- You also might have to cast the t_cust_nr to a diff. data type if needed.


SET NOCOUNT OFF;

DROP TABLE #tmp;
```